# Underlying PinchArea steals event from MultiPointTouchArea

Tags: android, qt, qml, multi-touch, event-propagation

I want to implement an on-screen control button, which can be pressed as a modifier for GUI interactions.

This is not possible to do with a `MouseArea` because that API can only handle one touch point in one mouse area.

That limitation does not apply to `MultiPointTouchArea` - you can have multiple of those and interact with them at the same time.

In my scenario, there is the control button, implemented via `MultiPointTouchArea`, on top of a `Flickable` that's inside of a `PinchArea`. The latter is being used to scale the view, which is implemented via the `Flickable`.

However, I encounter an issue with that arrangement, if the control button is pressed, I cannot interact with the flickable, laying a single finger on it while the button is pressed begins a pinch gesture. This is odd, what's expected is that the pinch only begins when there are two touch points within its area. For some reason, even though initially the touch is registered as an event of the button, the moment one touch point becomes active in the pinch area, the button touch point gets counted as being in the pinch area.

Note that this doesn't happen without either the flickable or the pinch area, both have to be present in that configuration. If it is just the flickable or just the pinch area, the overlay button works as expected. Also, the problem manifests even if the button is before the pinch area.

Here is the code reproducing the issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 1920
  height: 1080

  PinchArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPinchUpdated: tt.text = pinch.scale
    pinch.target: rect
    Flickable {
      contentWidth: 2000
      contentHeight: 2000
      anchors.fill: parent
      Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "green"
        x: 500
        y: 300
      }
    }
  }

  Text {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    id: tt
  }

  Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    color: "blue"
    MultiPointTouchArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      minimumTouchPoints: 1
      maximumTouchPoints: 1
      onPressed: parent.color = "red"
      onReleased: parent.color = "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that if you touch the flickable while the button is pressed, the pinch area gets triggered, and when releasing the button its color doesn't change, i.e. its released signal is not emitted, the event was effectively stolen from it by the pinch area, even thou the latter is behind and should not interfere. Alas, there is no `preventStealing` option in this scenario.

At this point this looks like [yet another Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58170), but suggestions on how to work around that issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours of investigating the issue, it seems that it is indeed a case of a bug or at least a significant design limitation. I wasn't able to get overlapping touch areas work simultaneously no matter what, and even if they are not overlapping or nested, the behavior is clunky with bogus touch points being registered between different areas.

Luckily, in my case I was able to work around the issue by avoiding overlapping - I nudged the pinch area to the right, while the underlying flickable was still effectively filling the screen by having it offset in the negative x axis:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 1920
  height: 1080

  PinchArea {
    height: parent.height //
    x: btn.width //
    width: parent.width - x //
    Flickable {
      contentWidth: 2000
      contentHeight: 2000
      height: parent.height //
      width: main.width //
      x: -btn.x //
      Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "green"
        x: 500
        y: 300
      }
    }
  }

  Text {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    id: tt
  }

  Rectangle {
    id: btn
    width: 200
    height: 200
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    color: "blue"
    MultiPointTouchArea {
      anchors.fill: parent
      minimumTouchPoints: 1
      maximumTouchPoints: 1
      onPressed: parent.color = "red"
      onReleased: parent.color = "blue"
    }
  }
}
```

However, if your case calls for simultaneous use of overlapping touch areas, it appears you are out of luck until the bug gets sorted out.